# Laravel / GuzzleHttp - get request without waiting for response

Tags: laravel, get, request, guzzle

I'm making a get request with GuzzleHttp:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->get('URL');
```

Actually, the URL is an API which make some changes (and might take some time) - there is a way to send the request without waiting for response?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do in the bigger picture, you might make use of Laravel's [queued jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues) or  [guzzle promises](https://github.com/guzzle/promises#features).

Comment: I know that is not what you are asking for but If your API URL is making some changes (and you own the API), you may want to reconsider the http method of the request.